# How to add drilldown to stacked column chart?

Tags: highcharts

I have seen the demo for drill down column chart, but I want to add it to stacked column chart.

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown

There is no drill down option in data series for stacked columm ? e.g.

```
"series":[
    {
        "name":"John",
        "data":[5],
        "drilldown":[
            {"name":"a","data":[25]},
            {"name":"b","data":[43]},
            {"name":"c","data":[24]},
            {"name":"d","data":[23]}
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Right now only one series in drilldown is supported, see [that report](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2604).

Comment: This now works out of the box ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/s5JqN/)).